# jQuery Collapsible Panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

ASP.Net, 2.0 VS2005, .Net 2.0 jQuery 1.8.3, jQuery UI 1.9.2

I have two panels (more will come later on) on my form that can be open or closed at the users request.

i am using the jQuery '.slideToggle' method.

This is my markup

```
<div class="trigger0">Collapsible Header 1 - Click to toggle</div>
            <div class="panel0">
                content 1
            </div>
           <div class="trigger1">Collapsible Header 2 - Click to toggle</div>
            <div class="panel1">
                content 2
            </div>
```

The following works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".trigger0").click(function(){
            $(".panel0").slideToggle("medium");
        });
        $(".trigger1").click(function() {
            $('.panel1').slideToggle("medium");
        });
    });
```

but this doesn't

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        for (var vReportSectionCount = 0; vReportSectionCount < 2; vReportSectionCount++)
        {
            $(".trigger" + vReportSectionCount).click(function(){
                $(".panel" + vReportSectionCount).slideToggle("medium");
            });
        }
    });
```

As i dont yet know how many panels will finally exist i dont want to have to write a new line for every panel. Can someone explain to me why and propose a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be something you're looking for? This lets you name the classes as classes and not ID's

HTML

```
<div class="trigger">Collapsible Header 1 - Click to toggle</div>
<div class="panel">
    content 1
</div>

<div class="trigger">Collapsible Header 2 - Click to toggle</div>
<div class="panel">
    content 2
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("medium");
    });
});
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LkTf8/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) not to do a staff that has been already done :)